# Disable app start on dock connection

Tags: samsung

I use chinese usb hub with my device. it also could serve as microsd reader, I don't need this functionality but everytime I connect device - I got message asking me to choose which app (file managers) to use. Is it possible to somehow disable this behaviour?

Android 13 (of samsung variety). Samsung Galaxy Z Fold 3 and Samsung Galaxy Tab Active 3